# Google::Apis::AuthorizationError (Unauthorized)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-client

We are creating an application with Ionic framework as front-end and Ruby on Rails as back-end. We are able to link Gmail account in our app. Account linking is working fine, we get **serverAuthCode** from front-end and then using that we get refresh token and we are able to fetch emails with that refresh token at first attempt. But within seconds, it get expired or revoked. Getting the following issue:

```
Signet::AuthorizationError (Authorization failed.  Server message:
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked."
})
```

It seems like, refresh token itself is expiring in seconds. Does anyone have any idea about how to fix it?

Update:

Existing code looks like this:

```
class User   
  def authentication(linked_account)
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    token_credential_uri: Rails.application.secrets.token_credential_uri,
    client_id: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
    client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    redirect_uri: Rails.application.secrets.redirect_uri,
    refresh_token: linked_account[:refresh_token]
  )

  client.update!(access_token: linked_account.token, expires_at: linked_account.expires_at)
  return  AccessToken.new(linked_account.token) unless client.expired?
  auth.fetch_access_token! 
 end

 def get_email(linked_account)
   auth = authentication(linked_account)
   gmail = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
   gmail.client_options.application_name = User::APPLICATION_NAME
   gmail.authorization = AccessToken.new(linked_account.token)
   query = "(is:inbox OR is:sent)"
   gmail.list_user_messages(linked_account[:uid], q: "#{query}")
   ## Getting error over here ^^
  end
end // class end 

class AccessToken
  attr_reader :token
  def initialize(token)
    @token = token
  end

  def apply!(headers)
    headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{@token}"
  end
end
```

Reference link: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/296

Comment: What is the SCOPE you are sending? Do you have a minimal repo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to catch the error and use auth.fetch_access_token and then trying again? This may happen when user has changed recently password and access to gmail api is revoked automatically by Google api.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Please check the following repo **https://github.com/MeenakshiNaik/oauth2sample**. In this repo, all ouath code is there

Comment: @mico Yes I tried using auth.fetch_access_token but same issue is occurring with new access_token too which i get from auth.fetch_access_toke

Comment: Does the token get expired/revoked only if you use it, or does the very first request fail too if you wait some time before sending it?

Comment: @MeeSN I am not sure whether 'client.update' method can help but you can give a try, as mentioned in https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/signet/Signet/OAuth2/Client

Answer (score 2):

From what I can guess the issue seems to be on these two lines. The way token expiry is being checked and the new token is being generated. It would be great if there is minimal reproducible code.

```
return  AccessToken.new(linked_account.token) unless client.expired?
auth.fetch_access_token!
```

Here is how I get my access token:

```
  def self.access_token(refresh_token)
    Cache.fetch(refresh_token, expires_in: 60.minutes) do
      url = GoogleService::TOKEN_CREDENTIAL_URI
      # p.s. TOKEN_CREDENTIAL_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
      _, response = Request.post(
        url,
        payload: {
          "client_id": GoogleService::CLIENT_ID,
          "client_secret": GoogleService::CLIENT_SECRET,
          "refresh_token": refresh_token,
          "grant_type": "refresh_token"
        }
      )
      response['access_token']
    end
  end
```

And then use this access token for any purpose. Let me know how it goes and also if you are able to create a reproducible version of the API. That will be great.

Comment: can add few more code .. like how are you using it with `google_api_client` gem api .. when do you fetch the a new access_token (do you do it always) or when it is about to expire. May I can take some pointer from there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried refreshing the access token with the refresh token? You can catch the error and retry.

Something like this:

```
begin
  gmail.list_user_messages(linked_account[:uid], q: "#{query}")
rescue Google::Apis::AuthorizationError => exception
  client.refresh!
  retry
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough code is posted, but what is posted looks wrong.

- `linked_account` is not defined
- Nowhere is it shown that `linked_account.token` is ever updated (or set, for that matter). It needs to be updated when the `refresh_token` is used to get a new access token.
- `auth` appears to be undefined in the line `auth.fetch_access_token!`
- `GmailService#authorization=` takes a `Signet::OAuth2::Client` not an `AccessToken`.

Probably what is happening is that you have a valid access token in `linked_account.token` until you call `client.update!`, which fetches a new access token and invalidates the old one. But since you never update `linked_account`, future calls fail until you go through the code path that resets it.

You only need to call `client.update!` if the access token has expired, and if it has expired and you get a new one, you need to store that new one in `linked_account.token`.

Comment: Please check repo, all oauth latest code is there: https://github.com/MeenakshiNaik/oauth2sample

Comment: @MeeSN the repo is different code than the post. `GmailService#authorization=` takes a `Signet::OAuth2::Client` not an `AccessToken`, so that is part of your problem. It still appears you are also needlessly refreshing the access token. Plus there is a syntax error (missing parenthesis) in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

The thought that the `refresh token` will never expire is actually a misunderstanding. The actual scene is that the server issues a short-lived access token and a long lived refresh token. So in reality what happens is that the access token can be regained using the long lived refresh tokens but yes, you will have to request a new refresh token (as it expires too !). For example; you may treat refresh tokens as if they never expire. However on sign-in check for a new one, in case the user revokes the refresh token, in this scenario, Google will provide a new refresh token on sign-in so just update the refresh token.

Now the condition can be that the user revokes access to your application. In this case, the `refresh token` will expire (or I should actually say that it would become an unauthorized one). So if that is the scenario in your case, you will have to think on avoiding the revoking of access for the application.

For better understanding of it, you may refer to this [document](http://hueniverse.com/2010/05/introducing-oauth-2-0/) and even [OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why a refresh token would stop working.

1. It gets to old refresh tokens expire after six months if not used.
2. A user can reauthecate your application and get a new refresh token both refresh tokens will work you can have a max of fifty outstanding refresh tokens then the first will stop working.
3. the user can revoke your access.
4. Wakey daylight savings time bug of 2015. *(we wont talk about that)*

Gmail and reset password.

This is mostly like due to a password reset. OAuth grants with the gmail scopes are revoked when a user changes their password.

See [Automatic OAuth 2.0 token revocation upon password change](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6328616)

In general, users can revoke grants at any time. You should be able to handle that case gracefully and alert the user that they need to reauthorize if they wish to continue using the functionality provided.

You have been doing a lot of testing i would guess are you saving the newest refresh token?  If not then you may be using old refresh tokens and the will stop working.  (number 2)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, only youtube **upload** api raise

```
Unauthorized (Google::Apis::AuthorizationError)
```

and other api, like list videos api work well

it's because i use new google account and have not up video

i manually up video in youtube web, youtube require me create "channel"

and I try youtube up api again, it work

I guess it's because youtube has channel to up